# Как сделать запрос с помощью HttpWebRequest который редиректит на другой урл?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Подскажите, как или что нужно исользовать, что бы отправить реквест по ссылке, в которой зашит редирект на другой урл? Я каждый раз получаю ошибку 302, и не знаю как это исправить.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(request.GetResponse().ResponseUri);
```

ломается все на строке

```
request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(request.GetResponse().ResponseUri);
```

Пробовал с разными методами в хедере, но не работает ни с ками.

Comment: `request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;` на `true`, нет?

Comment: 302 это не ошибка, а уведомление о [временном редиректе](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#3xx)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не работает ни так ни так.

Comment: @ГеннадийП суть не совем в этом, мне необходимо как то обратится к этому урлу с редиректом, что тот сервис к которому обращаюсь запустилась нужная служба.

Comment: @MainStar Редирект бывает по двум причинам - 1. Это надо серверу (новый  адрес API, или сменить банально HTTP на HTTPS). 2. Это неверные отправные данные запроса (например данные авторизации, при неверных данных определенные ресурсы перекидывают на другой адрес с ошибкой No access или что то в этом духе). В общем, редирект - это последствие тех или иных действий и бороться с этим, это значит что вы делаете что то не так...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в данном случае редирект происходит по другой причине. Ссылка к которой необходимо обратится я получаю ее с емейла, я на почту полчаю гиперссылку, которая сначала делает запрос на мой сервис, что бы запустить нужную мне службу, а после открывает зашитую в нее вторую ссылку. Но когда я обращаюсь к полученной ссылке из емейла, то получаю только это оповещание 302.